# Gulp task to comment out

Tags: javascript, gulp

I are there any gulp tasks to comment out lines of code? I know of plenty of tasks that delete lines, but i want to comment out e.g

```
line1  var a = 'mr';
line2  var b = 'mrs;
line3  var c = 'apple';
line4  var d = 'plum';
line5  var e = 'pear';
line6  var f = 'hat';
line7  var g = 'table';
line8  var h = 'spoon';
line9  var i = 'car';
line10  var j = 'ladder';
```

With the above, i would like to comment out for example line2 and line6 so result would be:

```
line1  var a = 'mr';
//line2  var b = 'mrs;
line3  var c = 'apple';
line4  var d = 'plum';
line5  var e = 'pear';
//line6  var f = 'hat';
line7  var g = 'table';
line8  var h = 'spoon';
line9  var i = 'car';
line10  var j = 'ladder';
```

Comment: Just out of interest.. Why would you do this ?

Comment: Anyway : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert

Comment: what if you have there a genuine comment or documentation?

Comment: @Pogrindis I have a node api with a react interface that I test locally. I need to comment out "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for allowing local connections... Also, I have http locally instead of https. So I would just comment out "https.createServer" and comment in "app.listen" or vis-versa. That would be my use case

Comment: https://github.com/ryanolsonx/gulp-dev allows you to toggle designated code - but apparently only in html because it looks for html comments.  It looks like it could be modified to work with any comment style without too much difficulty...

Answer (score 0):

On NPM...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncomment
Looks like "gulp-uncomment" will help to remove unnecessary comments for production...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-code
And "gulp-strip-code" will allow you to remove blocks of code that you don't want. Essentially 'commenting' them out...